# Cut down a string in text area within particular limit in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text area in my user description form . I need to cut down the string , if user enter more than 100 chars. **I want to use jquery for this**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply use this

```
$('#textarea').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val().slice(0, 100));
});
```

Comment: You probably meant: `$('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val().substr(0, 100));`

Comment: @gdoronissupportingMonica For the OP's use-case slice should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textarea').bind('keyup keydown blur', function() {
   $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, 100));
})
```

Comment: Why so much unnecessary bindings? One is enough

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
  if(this.value.length > 100){
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, 100);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

    $('#test').val($('#test').val().slice(0, 100));

});
```

​

check demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ycDfb/

Answer (score 0):

For better result restrict the text or `keypress` event

```
var maxchar = 100;
$('textarea').keypress(function(e){
  if($(this).val().length > maxchar){
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxchar));
  }
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/zZ7KT/)